# Missing thumbnail image in share of Page Tab App url

Tags: facebook

I have a Page Tab app on Facebook currently and want to promote it in the timeline, but when I do I'm not getting a thumbnail.

I've added in the thumbnail meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="MY_IMAGE"/>
```

but it's still not showing - am I missing something?  The link to the image is actually in the app code itself and points to an image 111 x 74px in the images folder of the app, so it's not on a different site or anything - and it's an absolute link.

The app link is here FYI: https://www.facebook.com/ValerieCafe/app_451324494932654

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.i-wl.co.uk%2Fpvfacebook%2F

Comment: This actually led me to a fix - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know there was a debugger for Facebook apps online:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I'd missed the meta tags out, and actually the way the app was built was not letting Facebook crawl it properly so once I figured out all those problems it works fine.  Although, Facebook does seem very slow if you want to change the image used as a thumbnail - it needs at least 24hrs to catch up.